# Django multiple files in one input can't be read by server

Tags: django, file-upload

When I submit to Django a multiple files upload form

```
<input type="file" name="files" multiple />
```

I get a sensible result in `request.FILES`:

```
(MultiValueDict: {u'files': [(InMemoryUploadedFile: 0202.jpg (image/jpeg)), (InMemoryUploadedFile: 0203.jpg (image/jpeg))]})
```

But then my confusion starts. I thought `request.FILES['files']` would contain a couple of files (appears to be a list), but it shows only

```
0203.jpg
```

No `InMemoryUploadedFile` part and more importantly: only the last file!

Looping through `request.FILES` with `.iteritems()` only goes over that one file too, `request.FILES['files']` is distinctly uniterable; the below code actually froze up the console and made it beep endlessly:

```
for v in request.FILES['files']:
    print v
    print type(v)
```

So... Is any of this this normal? What am I doing wrong?

As I'm starting to think this may be a bug: I'm using Django 1.4.2 with Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out the answer was on Stack Overflow after all, on a slightly different (client side, at least) problem here: [multiple files upload using same input name in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851336/multiple-files-upload-using-same-input-name-in-django)

Turns out that `request.FILES['files']` was wrong and should have been `request.FILES.getlist('file')`.

Why this is the case is a complete mystery to me. If anyone can answer with an explanation, I'll gladly switch the accepted answer.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46409022/5512755 For a more extended explanation on the reason.