# Django: Uploading multiple files. List of files needed in cleaned_data['file']

Tags: django, file-upload

I followed the pattern of the docs, to upload several files with one `forms.FileField`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files

Unfortunately `cleaned_data['file']` does contain one file, not both files.

What needs to be done to have all uploaded files on `cleaned_data['file']`?

Here is the code from the docs:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class FileFieldForm(forms.Form):
    file_field = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .forms import FileFieldForm

class FileFieldView(FormView):
    form_class = FileFieldForm
    template_name = 'upload.html'  # Replace with your template.
    success_url = '...'  # Replace with your URL or reverse().

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file_field')
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                ...  # Do something with each file.
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

**Update**

There is a pull request to solve this issue: https://github.com/django/django/pull/9011

Comment: Can you add some code to the question?

Comment: The example shows accessing the list of files in the view, via the request.FILES.getlist('file_field') call, rather than via the form fields. I would suspect that's where the issue is, but can't know for sure without seeing some code.

Comment: Yes some example of the code pattern you are using would be great to try spotting a possible error or some configuration it might be lacking.

Comment: I suggested an edit with some code which has been rejected. So here it goes...  
# forms.py
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.FileField(
        widget=ClearableFileInput(
            attrs={'multiple': True}))

In the views.py file, I want to access the files as a list through the variable form.cleaned_data['my_field']

# views.py
from .forms import MyForm
def post_view(request):
    form = MyForm(
        request.POST,
        request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        files = form.cleaned_data['my_field']
        # Do something

Comment: Oh god... WHY, on Earth, adding example code as example is "intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit" ?

Comment: @Dunatotatos I added the code from the docs.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :)

Answer (score 23):

## What happens

When your run `form.is_valid()`, the fields are validated and cleaned one after one, and stored in the `cleaned_data` variable. If you look at the Django source code, you'll find that your form fields go through an individual validation in the `_clean_fields` methods of the class `BaseForm` in the file `django/forms/forms.py`

The validation is made according to the widget type (*ie* `forms.ClearableFileInput` in the case of the field you are interested in). Going a bit deeper shows you that the `cleaned_data` is filled with `files.get(name)` where `files` is the list of the updated files, and `name` is the name of the field currently being validated.

The type of `files` is `MultiValueDict`. If you look at the code in `django/utils/datastructures.py`, you'll find some interesting stuff around the line 48. I copy the docstring here :

> A subclass of dictionary customized to handle multiple values for the
>      same key.

```
>>> d = MultiValueDict({'name': ['Adrian', 'Simon'], 'position': ['Developer']})
>>> d['name']
'Simon'
>>> d.getlist('name')
['Adrian', 'Simon']
>>> d.getlist('doesnotexist')
[]
>>> d.getlist('doesnotexist', ['Adrian', 'Simon'])
['Adrian', 'Simon']
>>> d.get('lastname', 'nonexistent')
'nonexistent'
>>> d.setlist('lastname', ['Holovaty', 'Willison'])
```

> This class exists to solve the irritating problem raised by cgi.parse_qs,
>       which returns a list for every key, even though most Web forms submit
>       single name-value pairs.

As this behavior depends only on the widget of the field, I can see three different solutions from now.

## The solutions

1. You patch Django to have a correct behavior when the `attrs` of the widget is set to `multiple`. (I was about to do it, but I'm really not sure about the consequences.) I'll study that in depth and may submit a PR.
2. You create your own Widget, a children of `ClearableFileInput`, which override the `value_from_datadict` method to use `files.getlist(name)` instead of `file.get(name)`.
3. You use `request.FILES.getlist('your_filed_name')` as suggested by [Astik Anand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6794568/astik-anand), or any easier solution.

Let's take a closer look at the solution 2.
Here are some instructions to create your own widget based on `ClearableFileInput`. Unfortunately, it is not enough to make it work, as the data are sent through a cleaning process owned by the field. You must create your own `FileField` as well.

```
# widgets.py
from django.forms.widgets import ClearableFileInput
from django.forms.widgets import CheckboxInput

FILE_INPUT_CONTRADICTION = object()

class ClearableMultipleFilesInput(ClearableFileInput):
    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        upload = files.getlist(name) # files.get(name) in Django source

        if not self.is_required and CheckboxInput().value_from_datadict(
                data, files, self.clear_checkbox_name(name)):

            if upload:
                # If the user contradicts themselves (uploads a new file AND
                # checks the "clear" checkbox), we return a unique marker
                # objects that FileField will turn into a ValidationError.
                return FILE_INPUT_CONTRADICTION
            # False signals to clear any existing value, as opposed to just None
            return False
        return upload
```

This part is basically taken word by word from the methods of `ClearableFileInput`, except the first line of `value_from_datadict` which was `upload = files.get(name)`.

As mentioned before, you also have to create your own `Field` to override the `to_python` method of `FileField` which tries to access a `self.name` and `self.size` attributes.

```
# fields.py
from django.forms.fields import FileField
from .widgets import ClearableMultipleFilesInput
from .widgets import FILE_INPUT_CONTRADICTION

class MultipleFilesField(FileField):
    widget = ClearableMultipleFilesInput

    def clean(self, data, initial=None):
        # If the widget got contradictory inputs, we raise a validation error
        if data is FILE_INPUT_CONTRADICTION:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_message['contradiction'], code='contradiction')
        # False means the field value should be cleared; further validation is
        # not needed.
        if data is False:
            if not self.required:
                return False
            # If the field is required, clearing is not possible (the widg    et
            # shouldn't return False data in that case anyway). False is not
            # in self.empty_value; if a False value makes it this far
            # it should be validated from here on out as None (so it will be
            # caught by the required check).
            data = None
        if not data and initial:
            return initial
        return data
```

And here is how to use it in your form:

```
# forms.py
from .widgets import ClearableMultipleFilesInput
from .fields import MultipleFilesField

your_field = MultipleFilesField(
    widget=ClearableMultipleFilesInput(
        attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

And it works!

```
>>> print(form.cleaned_data['your_field']
[<TemporaryUploadedFile: file1.pdf (application/pdf)>, <TemporaryUploadedFile: file2.pdf (application/pdf)>, <TemporaryUploadedFile: file3.pdf (application/pdf)>]
```

Of course, this solution cannot be used directly and needs a lot of improvements. Here, we basically erase all the checking made in the `FileField` field, we do not set a maximum number of files, the `attrs={'multiple': True}` is redundant with the widget name, and many similar things. As well, I am pretty sure I missed some important methods in the `FileField` or `ClearableFileInput`. This is only a starting idea, but you'll need much more work, and a look at the [widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) and [fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/) on the official documentation.

Comment: Wow, great answer. Thank you

Comment: self.error_message['contradiction'] should be self.error_messages['contradiction'].
Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 8):

I assume that you have:

```
class FileFieldForm(forms.Form):
     files = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

and you are trying to get `files` using : `cleaned_data['files']` and you are getting only 1 file instead of 2.

> The Reason:

What is happening here is, When you try to do something like this

```
file in self.cleaned_data['files]:,
```

thinking that, you can iterate over a list of uploadedFile objects and pass each to the handler function.

But `cleaned_data['files']` is not a list for you, it's just ONE single instance of uploadedfile.

When you iterate over a file object, you're actually reading it. So what you pass eventually to the handler function is not the file object but its content (as a bytes string).

> The solution

You need to get a list of files and then, perform something what you want on them as below.

```
files = request.FILES.getlist('files')

for f in files:
    ...  # Do something with each file considering f as file object
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this work-around. Yes, this works, but it is a work-around in my eyes. A form can have prefix. If I use `request.FILES.getlist('files')` in the code of the form, the prefix is not used ... I love the "seperation of conerns" which I get from the nice django form library. AFAIK this is the only part where I need to access the requests object directly. I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Awesome, this works for me, so instead using the save method on the form class, because there I don't have access to the request object Im overriding on the save_model method on the ModelAdmin Class

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library: https://github.com/Chive/django-multiupload

> Django Multiupload
>
> Dead simple drop-in multi file upload field for django forms using
>   HTML5's multiple attribute.