# Binding Multiple Files to Django ImageField Form Widget

Tags: django, forms, input

Previously my Django form had a field that supported uploading a single file:

```
image = forms.ImageField(required=False, help_text=_('Optional image (2.5 MB or less)'), allow_empty_file=True)
```

If the user tried to edit the form after submitting it, I displayed the previously uploaded file by binding it to the form like so:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
else:
    data = {'title': model.title}
    file = {'image': model.file}
    form = MyForm(data, file, instance=model)
```

To enable uploading multiple files, I've now changed the widget to:

```
image = forms.ImageField(required=False, help_text=_('Optional image (2.5 MB or less)'), allow_empty_file=True, widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

This works fine when uploading the files, but I can't find a way to bind more than one file to the form when it comes to editing it.

Is there a solution using the current widget, or would it involve using a custom or multiple widgets?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible with the standard widget.

A `ClearableFileInput` with `multiple` enabled provides access to the selected files via a `MultiValueDict`.

You can bind a `MultiValueDict` to an `ImageField` when initialising the form, but it will only ever bind the last image. This is because the widget extends `FileInput`, and its function `value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name)` returns `files.get(name)`, rather than `files.getlist(name)`.

So, in short, you have to come up with a custom solution. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46409022/6619548) helped me to see this.