# How to upload more than 2 files once in Django?

Tags: django, web, file-upload

I put two files in web, but I can only get one file always.

in web

[image]

in `form.py`

```
    class UFileForm(forms.Form):
        file = forms.FileField(label="资料文件上传", widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True, 'class': 'bg-info'}))
```

in `view.py`

```
class UploadFileView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        data = {}
        form = UFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file')
        # print files in request here
        print(files)
```

result is:

```
[<InMemoryUploadedFile: 20220609奥莉公会-积分统计表.xlsx (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet)>]
```

why there is only one file?

Answer (score 1):

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46409022/14338747 for help using `ClearableFileInput` functionality with multiple file uploads.

Also, from the [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files). Your `views.py` must be updated to:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .forms import UFileForm

class FileFieldFormView(FormView):
    form_class = UFileForm
    template_name = 'upload.html'  # Replace with your template.
    success_url = '...'  # Replace with your URL or reverse().

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('file')
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                ...  # Do something with each file.
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```